# enum value to constructor class JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor, enums

Hi there I'm creating the beans of the tables of my database, but I have this little issue that I can't pass the ENUM value to the constructor,  I solved it but when I try to set the value It says error; 
here is my code

```
public class HorariosBean {
    private Integer idHorario;
    private String dia;
    private Integer hora;
    private enum estado {DISPONIBLE, NODISPONIBLE};
    private Integer depasId;

    // this is the first thing I fix for pass the enum
    public HorariosBean(Integer idHorario, String dia, Integer hora, estado estate, Integer depasId) {
        this.idHorario = idHorario;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.hora= hora;
        this.estado = estate; //error is here says "estado cannot be resolved or is not a field"
        this.depasId = depasId;
    }
}
```

I cannot change the type cuz I have other tables with enums so that implies I should change everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private enum estado {DISPONIBLE, NODISPONIBLE};` is meaning you declared a `enum`, not a variable.

So add new line:

```
private estado yourEnum;
```

And update your constructor:

```
this.yourEnum = estate;
```

Comment: And rename estado to Estado as it's a class

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, but there is another problem.

You can't go with that enum declared as *private*. You see, you want to pass an instance of that enum to the constructor of that class.

But no other class will be able to use that enum, for example in a *new HorariosBean* statement, as the enum is private.

Beyond: don't trick yourself into believing that making an error very often is a good reason to not fix that problem. In other words: if you made the same mistake repeatedly, then you have to touch all that code. Therefore it is so important to avoid code duplication.